# Atom package to save header/footer html code

Tags: html, package, atom-editor

I am using Atom IDE, I am searching for a package where I can store my header, footer etc code and simply put them in other pages, so I have to edit header footer in one place, I used to do this in Dreamweaver but not sure how to do that in Atom.

Comment: just to be clear you need something like `code snippet` in `Atom` so that you can have that complete header, footer code part in 2 3 easy keys ??

Comment: Yes, or maybe something where we can store code as a controller/placeholder for any kind of section not specifically header footer.

Comment: In that case you can create your own custom snippets in atom [Reference link](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)

Comment: Will it change by itself in all places If I change at one place?

Comment: It will be saved in your settings file which is global to your atom text editor and you can make it language specific as in you can make the snippet command `cg` for `console.log` in `javascript` and something else in `.html` files

Comment: I have posted the answer as well, with some more details. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your custom snippets in `Atom IDE` as well for that you will have to modify your `snippets.cson` file which is present in your `%USERPROFILE%\.atom`.

You can refer to Atom's flight manual docs: [Creating your own Snippets](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/#creating-your-own-snippets).

And if you need multi line snippet you can have a look at: [Multi line snippet body](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/#multi-line-snippet-body)